# python: filter() an iterable, count filtered and not filtered items

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, filter, iterator

I have a big `Iterable`.
and i want to filter it using `filter()` function.
how can i count (in some elegant way) how many items are filtered?
(same question could be for `map()`, `reduce()` etc)

sure i can just make:

```
items = get_big_iterable()
count_good = 0
count_all = 0
for item in items:
    if should_keep(item):
        count_good += 1
    count_all += 1

print('keep: {} of {}'.format(count_good, count_all))
```

is it somehow possible with `filter()`?

```
items = filter(should_keep, get_big_iterable()) 
for item in items:
    #... using values here ..
    #possible count not filtered items here too?
```

I should not iterate twice, and would like to use `filter()` or similar solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward with `enumerate`, and some basic arithmetic:

```
def should_keep(x):
    return x % 3 == 0

items = range(1, 28)


def _wrapper(x):
    return should_keep(x[1])

filtered_with_counts = enumerate(filter(_wrapper, enumerate(items, 1)), 1)

for i, (j, item) in filtered_with_counts:
    # do something with item
    print(f"Item is {item}, total: {j}, good: {i}, bad: {j-i}")

count_all = j
count_good = i
count_bad = count_all - count_good
print(f"Final: {count_all}, {count_good}, {count_bad}")
```

Output:

```
Item is 3, total: 3, good: 1, bad: 2
Item is 6, total: 6, good: 2, bad: 4
Item is 9, total: 9, good: 3, bad: 6
Item is 12, total: 12, good: 4, bad: 8
Item is 15, total: 15, good: 5, bad: 10
Item is 18, total: 18, good: 6, bad: 12
Item is 21, total: 21, good: 7, bad: 14
Item is 24, total: 24, good: 8, bad: 16
Item is 27, total: 27, good: 9, bad: 18
Final: 27, 9, 18
```

I probably wouldn't use this though. Note, I assume you may not want to modify `should_keep`, but you can always wrap it.

Comment: i think the other answers are more useful for real systems, but this fits best as answer for my question :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I can think of: first one is short, but is probably not good for performance and defeat the purpose of having an iterator:

```
count=len(list(your_filtered_iterable))
```

Another way is to write your own filter. Per Python documentation:

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to the generator
>   expression `(item for item in iterable if function(item))` if function
>   is not None and `(item for item in iterable if item)` if function is
>   None.

So you can write something like this:

```
class Filter:
    def __init__(self, func, iterable):
        self.count_good = 0
        self.count_all = 0
        self.func = func
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.func is None:
            for obj in self.iterable:
                if obj:
                    self.count_good += 1
                    self.count_all += 1
                    yield obj
                else:
                    self.count_all += 1
        else:
            for obj in self.iterable:
                if self.func(obj):
                    self.count_good += 1
                    self.count_all += 1
                    yield obj
                else:
                    self.count_all += 1
```

Then you can access the `count_good` and `count_all` from the `Filter` instance:

```
items = Filter(should_keep, get_big_terable()) 
    for item in items:
        # do whatever you need with item
        print('keep: {} of {}'.format(items.count_good, items.count_all))
```

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `filter` does not provide that. You need to write your own filter class, implementing its `__next__` and `__iter__` methods.

#### Code

```
class FilterCount:
    def __init__(self, function, iterable):
        self.function = function
        self.iterable = iter(iterable)
        self.countTrue, self.countFalse = 0, 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        nxt = next(self.iterable)
        while not self.function(nxt):
            self.countFalse += 1
            nxt = next(self.iterable)

        self.countTrue += 1
        return nxt
```

#### Example

```
lst = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar']
filtered_lst = FilterCount(lambda x: x == 'foo', lst)

for x in filtered_lst:
    print(x)
print(filtered_lst.countTrue)
print(filtered_lst.countFalse)
```

#### Output

```
foo
foo
2
1
```

Comment: i need the filtered values to iterate too, not only count. How to access them in this case?

Comment: @ya_dimon I see what you need now, see updated answer

Comment: would you explain why its different from @pkqxdd answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852326/2519073 , do we need the __next__ and not __iter__? (its another question i know, but just in case you have time..)

Comment: @ya_dimon a solution using `__next__` is stateful, this means if you partially iterate over it, and then come back to it you will continue from where you left while a solution using `__iter__` alone is stateless, whenever you start iterating over it, you go back to the start. With that regard, this solution is closer to filter

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the sum() function, e.g.:

```
count = sum(1 for x in get_big_iterable() if should_keep(x))
```